# IDEs besides Leo for cloning, aliasing, multi-viewing nodes/files?

Tags: ide, editor, mps

I am searching for IDEs/editors that will allow me to collect and edit subsets of the same files in multiple different views. This is precisely Leo's cloned node feature: Changes in a node are mirrored in the clone and vice versa. An analogy might be symbolic links or aliasing in a file system. (This is not the same as copying a file where edits to an original and the copy are independent.)

Leo is very cool, but I'm wondering if this feature is available in other IDEs. I am happy to pay for ease-of-use, stability, and polish.

(Bonus: Can I do this in Jetbrains' MPS? It doesn't seem like it from my playing around.)

Comment: MPS only supports one editor for a concept. But this is on the roadmap for 3.0. From [MPS Roadmap](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/MPS/MPS+public+roadmap) : 3.0 will enable defining new editors for existing concepts, for example, in sub-languages, and then viewing programs in different "guises" by changing the editor as you go.